# Add data into database using JSON(need to avoid duplicate of data php)

Tags: php, json, database

This is my JSON data,I need to insert these data into my database. Then each 5 minites,I will use setinterval to check if there is any new radio station added in this JSON file, if there is a change, it should only add the new one only. But am having issues, all the field is being added once again. I dont need duplicate data, I only want the new updated radio station to be added.

```
[

{
    "stationname": "Radio Plus, Mauritius",
    "websiteurl": "www.radioplus.mu",
    "streamurl": "http://s4.voscast.com:8432/;",
    "genre":"POP (Popular Music)",
    "language":"French",
    "country": "Mauritius",
    "description":"Best Music"
},


{
    "stationname": "Radio One",
    "websiteurl": "r1.mu",
    "streamurl": "http://151.80.44.127:8020/stream?type=http&nocache",
    "genre":"POP (Popular Music)",
    "language":"French",
    "country": "Mauritius",
    "description":"24/7 Music Everyday"
},

{
    "stationname": "2RRR FM",
    "websiteurl": "www.2rrr.org",
    "streamurl": "http://110.142.218.7:88/broadwave.m3u?type=.mp3/;s",
    "genre":"Electronic",
    "language":"English",
    "country": "Austria",
    "description":"Good Music all day and night"
},

{
    "stationname": "22G Radio",
    "websiteurl": "www.22gradio.com",
    "streamurl": "http://s6.voscast.com:9224/;stream.mp3",
    "genre":"Electronic",
    "language":"English",
    "country": "India",
    "description":"Good Music in India"
},

{
    "stationname": "80’s / 90’s Radio",
    "websiteurl": "hitconnection.fr",
    "streamurl": "http://streaming.radionomy.com/80-s-90-s-HitConnectionRadio",
    "genre":"Electronic",
    "language":"French",
    "country": "French",
    "description":"This online radio station provides twenty four hour (24h) mix of 80’s / 90’s of music. The station plays all the 80’s / 90’s music you love while striving to keep up with the desires of its listeners."
},

{
    "stationname": "FM Reggae Trade Radio",
    "websiteurl": "www.1.fm",
    "streamurl": "http://sc1c-sjc.1.fm:7078/;",
    "genre":"Raggae",
    "language":"Other",
    "country": "Brazil",
    "description":"Entertainment, Fun and excitement are the specialty of 1.FM Reggae Trade Radio the radio is always live and lively with its energetic presentation, promotion of music and programs. Its a complete package as a full entertainment rich radio broadcasting from Brazil With 1.FM Reggae Trade Radio you can enjoy lots of class leading musical programs."
},

{
    "stationname": "01 Internet of Music",
    "websiteurl": "www.internetofmusic.com",
    "streamurl": "http://radio.internetofmusic.com:8000/live.nsv",
    "genre":"World Music / Beats",
    "language":"English",
    "country": "United States of America",
    "description":"01 Internet of Music is all about good music as they believes “Music in the Answer”. By tuning in to 01 Internet of Music listeners from around the world can enjoy the amazingly entertaining musical programs presented by the talented broadcasting team of 01 Internet of Music."
},

{
    "stationname": "I love Kpop",
    "websiteurl": "www.ilovekpop.wifeo.com",
    "streamurl": "http://streaming.radionomy.com/IloveKpop?type=.mp3",
    "genre":"R&B / Soul",
    "language":"English",
    "country": "Korea North",
    "description":"In Korea there are lots of pop music based radio station available through out the whole country and I love Kpop is one of those popular radios broadcasting live from there. Unlike other radio stations of Korea this radio is always known best for broadcasting pop music along with musical information."
},

{
    "stationname": "2cr Radio",
    "websiteurl": "www.2cr.com.au",
    "streamurl": "http://s6.voscast.com:8016/;",
    "genre":"Pop (Popular music)",
    "language":"Japanese",
    "country": "China",
    "description":"2cr Radio is a very popular radio on China. They play Chines music, it is a 24 hrs online radio. Enjoy 2cr Radio."
},

{
    "stationname": "Akash",
    "websiteurl": "www.2cr.com.au",
    "streamurl": "http://s6.voscast.com:8016/;",
    "genre":"Pop (Popular music)",
    "language":"Japanese",
    "country": "China",
    "description":"2cr Radio is a very popular radio on China. They play Chines music, it is a 24 hrs online radio. Enjoy 2cr Radio."
}

]
```

This is my code for adding:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","registration");
$filename = "station.json";
$data = file_get_contents($filename);
$array = json_decode($data,true);

foreach($array as $roww){

$stationname = $roww['stationname'];
$sql_name = "SELECT * FROM radiotest WHERE stationname='$stationname'";
$res_name = mysqli_query($db, $sql_name);

}

foreach ($array as $row) {
if (mysqli_num_rows($res_name) > 0) {
return false;

}   else{
         $sql = "INSERT INTO radiotest(stationname,websiteurl,streamurl,genre,language,country,description) 
VALUES ('".$row["stationname"]."', '".$row["websiteurl"]."', '".$row["streamurl"]."', '".$row["genre"]."', '".$row["language"]."', '".$row["country"]."', '".$row["description"]."')";
mysqli_query($db,$sql);
}
}
?>
```

Can someone please help me ? how to avoid this ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming that the `streamurl` is unique, you can define a `getNewStations` method that returns only the stations which you haven't sent to the service. Of course, is the page is reloaded and you receive a JSON with stations already inserted in the server script, they'll be inserted again.

If this is an issue, you might have to define a way to check if an station is already in the database, maybe by checking that there is no other row with the same `streamurl` in the database.

In the example below, you'll see how `stations2` contains all the stations in `stations` and a new one. When you call `getNewStations` for that array, only the last one is returned.

```js
var insertedStations = {};

function getNewStations(stations) {
  var newStations = stations.filter(function(item) { return insertedStations[item.streamurl] === undefined});
  // add to list of inserted stations
  newStations.forEach(function(item) { insertedStations[item.streamurl] = true});
  
  return newStations
}

var stations = [
  {
    "stationname": "Radio Plus, Mauritius",
    "websiteurl": "www.radioplus.mu",
    "streamurl": "http://s4.voscast.com:8432/;",
    "genre":"POP (Popular Music)",
    "language":"French",
    "country": "Mauritius",
    "description":"Best Music"
  },
  {
    "stationname": "Radio One",
    "websiteurl": "r1.mu",
    "streamurl": "http://151.80.44.127:8020/stream?type=http&nocache",
    "genre":"POP (Popular Music)",
    "language":"French",
    "country": "Mauritius",
    "description":"24/7 Music Everyday"
  }
];

var stations2 = [
  {
    "stationname": "Radio Plus, Mauritius",
    "websiteurl": "www.radioplus.mu",
    "streamurl": "http://s4.voscast.com:8432/;",
    "genre":"POP (Popular Music)",
    "language":"French",
    "country": "Mauritius",
    "description":"Best Music"
  },
  {
    "stationname": "Radio One",
    "websiteurl": "r1.mu",
    "streamurl": "http://151.80.44.127:8020/stream?type=http&nocache",
    "genre":"POP (Popular Music)",
    "language":"French",
    "country": "Mauritius",
    "description":"24/7 Music Everyday"
  },
  {
    "stationname": "2cr Radio",
    "websiteurl": "www.2cr.com.au",
    "streamurl": "http://s6.voscast.com:8016/;",
    "genre":"Pop (Popular music)",
    "language":"Japanese",
    "country": "China",
    "description":"2cr Radio is a very popular radio on China. They play Chines music, it is a 24 hrs online radio. Enjoy 2cr Radio."
  }
];

var stationsToInsert = getNewStations(stations);
console.log(stationsToInsert);
stationsToInsert = getNewStations(stations2);
console.log(stationsToInsert); // should only log the third station
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but am still new to this..am not being able to understand your concepts..